# Shortest path in a k-partite graph which passes through each partition exactly once

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

Suppose $G$ is a connected undirected positive edge-weighted k-partite graph, and let $G_1, \cdots, G_k$ be the vertex partitions. Also assume that $G_1$ and $G_k$ have exactly one vertex each, call them $v_1$ and $v_k$ respectively. How does one determine if there exists a path between $v_1$ and $v_k$ which passes though each partition exactly once? And if its given that such paths exist, how does one find a shortest (sum of edge weights) one?

Comment: Presumably, you want some sort of efficient way to do so? Otherwise, brute force is an obvious method to do so. If so, you're going to need to define "efficient".

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a polynomial time algorithm; better if it can be done in O($n^2$), n being the number of vertices in $G$.

Comment: Is $k$ presumed constant as $n$ grows, then? If not, then how is the time allowed to depend on $k$?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in my earlier comment. For a fixed $k$, a quadratic complexity algorithm would also be great. Ideally, I would want the complexity to be polynomial in both $n$ and $k$.

Comment: There's a trivial $O(n^2 (k - 1)!)$ algorithm: list every permutation of $\{2, 3, \dots, k - 1\}$, and for each of them, only allow paths visiting the partitions in that order. I doubt it's possible to get polynomial in both $n$ and $k$, as that should solve the traveling salesman problem (by letting $k = n$).

Comment: Thank you. I get your point, although the (k-1)! term is not very encouraging. :)